# Task.Delay returned with Moq isn't awaited

Tags: c#, moq, mstest

The mock returns a delay-task but it's never awaited in `await service.DoAsync(token)`.
When I debug it just "skips" the `await service.DoAsync(token)` when it should wait long time.

**UnitTest**

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task Do_Test()
{
   var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
   var serviceMock = new Mock<IService>();
   serviceMock.Setup(_ => _.DoAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
              .Returns(Task.Delay(int.MaxValue, tokenSource.Token));

   var prog = new MyProg(serviceMock.Object)
   await prog.RunAsync(...);
   ...
   // assert
}
```

**MyProg**

```
public class Myprog
{
    public async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        await service.DoAsync(token);
        ...
    }
}
```

**IService**

```
public interface IService
{
   Task DoAsync(CancellationToken token);
}
```

**UPDATE**

I found a bug in my code. I had `new MyProg(new Mock<IService>())` instead of `new MyProg(serviceMock.Object)`

Comment: Please finish this code.  `IService` and `tokenSource` are not defined.  `Myprog` doesn't have the constructor you called, and there's various syntax missing.  It's hard to reproduce the issue if it doesn't compile.  I could try to infer what you meant, but then I might not have the same problem you're asking about.

Comment: What do you mean with, "it is never awaited". As far as I can see the Task.Delay will take 2147483647 ms to complete. Do you wait around 24 days for it to complete?

Comment: Also, you said the first part was from a unit test, but you didn't show the test method definition.  Have you perhaps defined the test method to return `void`?  It should return `Task`.

Comment: Where is the `tokenSource` defined? Is that a shared object?

Comment: @ewerspej, it's defined in the test. I forgot to add it. I've updated the post.

Comment: Is this your actual code or are you providing a different example based on your actual code?

Comment: Sorry, I found a bug in my code. I've posted the update in my post. Should I just close the  post?

Comment: You should also consider that with `.Returns(Task.Delay(...))`, if you call it a second time you'll get no delay, as the same task will be used, which is now completed, so you probably want to prefer `.Returns(() => Task.Delay(...))`.  Similarly, any delay between the `Setup()` and the invocation will be included in the delay, so if you e.g. wanted a delay for 2.5s, and took 0.5s to get to the invocation, you'd only get a 2s delay (with the way you have it).